# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'printSoln'

Tags: numpy, import, module

because its turn out like this

```
from printSoln import *
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'printSoln'

Im using printSoln how can i install that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Does this refer to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549998/printsoln-module-problem-modulenotfounderror ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is not any module named `printSoln`. This may be some custom `.py` file that has the functions which are used here.
I found one of its types file on GitHub: https://github.com/mateuv/MetodosNumericos/blob/master/python/NumericalMethodsInEngineeringWithPython/printSoln.py

you can download and write that code and save it in the same folder in which your code file exists.