# printSoln module problem, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, function, methods, module

i have the ebook for describe runge-kutta method, and its say i need module printSoln

```
def printSoln(X,Y,freq):

    def printHead(n):
        print("\n        x  ",end=" ")
        for i in range (n):
            print("      y[",i,"] ",end=" ")
        print()

    def printLine(x,y,n):
        print("{:13.4e}".format(x),end=" ")
        for i in range (n):
            print("{:13.4e}".format(y[i]),end=" ")
        print()
    
    m = len(Y)
    try: n = len(Y[0])
    except TypeError: n = 1
    if freq == 0: freq = m
    printHead(n)
    for i in range(0,m,freq):
        printLine(X[i],Y[i],n)
    if i != m - 1: printLine(X[m - 1],Y[m - 1],n)
```

but when i wanna import the module, the module cant define

```
import numpy as np
from printSoln import *
from run_kt4 import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

its say

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'printSoln'
```

how i fix this? please help

Comment: Thanks for your question. The Runge-Kutte method is a general method to solve differential equations for a given set of initial conditions. Many descriptions and implementations exist. The code from your e-book seems to define `printSoln` in its first line. I assume no import is necessary. The definition, however, is missing in the code you gave. `printSoln` probably stands for "print solution" which I would expect to contain some print statements. I suggest you double-check with your book.

Comment: You need to save the function in a file `printSoln.py` in the current directory or somewhere in the module path, or use the module directory option.